# Facebook GET friends API call not returning any friends besides those who are on the same app

Tags: facebook, request

In our game, we have been using the following block of code to retrieve and perform operations on the friends of the user who have not played our game.

```
FB.api '/me/friends?fields=installed,name,picture', (friendsList) ->
  if friendsList.error?
    // ... reject
    return
  friendsList = _(friendsList.data).filter (friend) -> not friend.installed
  // ... do something with the friends list
```

This worked fine until just recently (within the past week, just caught it today), when suddenly the friendsList being returned has a length of one before it gets filtered and includes just my only friend who has also installed the app and is currently playing it. The filter we're applying on the data isn't causing this because the data pre-filter only includes this one friend. The console isn't throwing any error, the response of friends just no longer includes anyone except the people who are also playing the app as far as I can tell. I definitely have friends who are not blocking apps from returning them in the results, too, so there should be at least some results.

What's going on? Did Facebook change their API recently for how this request works? I haven't been able to find any documentation on an update to the API recently, so I'm really confused as to why this block of code is no longer behaving as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem with my api. I think facebook will no longer allow to retrieve friends that didn't use the app before.

Comment: It's weird that they would make that sort of change without documenting it though. I thought this was what the [roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) was for?

Comment: It seems that issue has been solved. Do you still have problem?